# How set defaulte value for <select> with angular ng-repeat option?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to set a defaulte value for this drop-down but this doesn't work how I expected and I don't understand why?

```
<select ng-change="onChange()" ng-model="selectedInfo">
        <option value="" selected>Default</option>
        <option ng-repeat="(index, info) in infos" value="{{index}}">{{info.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I need to have in value the `index` number beacuse is used in angular controller.

What I have now is

[image]

And at click I have

[image]

And after I select one of this I have just 3 options

[image]

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve with

```
<select ng-change="onChange()" ng-model="selectedInfo" ng-init="selectedInfo = infos[0]">
        <option value="" [selected]="0">Default</option>
        <option ng-repeat="(index, info) in infos" value="{{index}}">{{info.name}}</option>
</select>
```